# Find the next several days time according to business hours

Tags: formula, businesshours

I need to build a formula based on the start time, order type and business hours. start time and due time are datetime.

The difficult part about this is I need to calculate this around the business hours. Which means say I need to find the due date 2 days after today, then I need to consider the local business hours whether it will be a weekend and whether there will be a public holiday.

I haven't found related documents around this functionality. Is that doable via formula?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to consider the Weekends then you can do that using formula

[Calculate the number of days between two dates while excluding weekends or weekdays.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004526&type=1)

But there is no standard function available for Holidays. You can upvote this Idea

[Access holiday object from formulas and workflow](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BpWdAAK)
[Excluding Holidays Formula](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000I75dAAC)

But if you have dates available for public holiday then you can try suggestions from here

[Exclude holidays from my formula field that calculates business workdays](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A0000019QHUQA2)

But you need to update this formula every year to make it functional. Also it doesn't suitable for long run.

So the best you an do here is use `Trigger/Apex` to populate the field.